# How to ask “Are you ready?” in German?

Tags: translation

I am learning German and want to write to someone to ask if they are ready for when the visit me next week.

I know the word *fertig* means like *finished?* Or *done?*

I think I need to use the term *bereit* but that sort of translates to *prepared* so if I ask:

> Bist du bereit für London?

It translates to

> Are you prepared for London?

and I want to check this is the most common way of formulating the sentence!

Especially as there are other words like *klar*.

Comment: This seems like something Google translate can do for you and doesn't need further clarification. Also please don't use all caps.

Comment: Thanks, sorry! I did check google translate but wasn’t sure. Next time I’ll also add I am unsure if google translate is correct to help. Also, I won’t use Caps next time, I was just trying to make it easier to read.

Comment: This question shows effort, and asking someone to trust Google Translate is irresponsible. I do not think that it should have been closed.

Comment: It depends what you want to express, but the most common expression for *are you prepared for* is *Bist du vorbereitet auf*

Comment: Der "most common way" ist schwer festzustellen. Es gibt regionale Unterschiede, solche von Bildung und sozialem Status, Unterschiede zw. mündlichem und schriftlichem Gebrauch, je nach Alter des sich Äußernden usw.

Comment: Dict.cc suggests "Sind Sie soweit?"

Comment: @inflagranti Google Translate is absoluter Mist, especially for short idiomatic phrases.  ----- sahra ze: Could you add whether the person you are writing to will be adressed as Sie or Du?, and could you add the sentence in english that you would write to an english-speaking person in the exact same circumstances?

Comment: @bukwyrm thanks, I was thinking of using the Du form. I wanted to say the equivalent of “are you ready for your visit next week” I will add this in future. Thanks